# Left join not returning record with null

Tags: sql, join, null

Here's the structure of my database (used to collect info from a survey):

```
question_responses->answer_choices->subquestions->questions->survey
    |                                                         ^
    V                                                         |
submissions->response_group<----------------------------survey_deployment
```

where A->B  means A has the PK of B

So, I want to get the responses of a particular user; let's say that his submission pk is 1.  I had written the query

```
select  question_responses.answer_text
from    submissions      join question_responses on (question_responses.submission_pk = submission.pk)
                         join answer_choices     on (question_responses.answer_choices_pk = answer_choices.pk)
                         join subquestions       on (answer_choices.subquestions_pk = subquestions.pk)
                   right join questions          on (subquestions.questions_pk = questions.pk)
where       submissions.pk = 1
order by    questions.order
```

It is possible to not answer questions.  In such a case, there is no question_responses.pk recorded.  I would still like to be able to account for skipping, so I need this record to be returned, even if there is no response.  I thought that the `right join` would have accounted for this record, but apparently not.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a little confusing. You say question_responses will be missing, but you have that included in you first (inner) join?

Comment: That may be what my oversight is.  I was just linking tables together without a thought.  I will attempt to go around the other way and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `submissions.pk = 1` in the where clause this effectively turns your outer join into an inner join, since any missing submission will have a pk of null. and `null = 1` is not true.

You could rewrite your query using a LEFT JOIN, and selecting from questions:

```
select  question_responses.answer_text
from    questions
        left join (subquestions
            inner join answer_choices
                on answer_choices.subquestions_pk = subquestions.pk
            inner join question_responses
                on question_responses.answer_choices_pk = answer_choices.pk
            inner join submissions
                on question_responses.submission_pk = submission.pk)
            on subquestions.questions_pk = questions.pk
            and submissions.pk = 1
order by    questions.order;
```

This is similar to doing something like:

```
select  subquery.answer_text
from    questions
        left join 
        (   select question_responses.answer_text, subquestions.questions_pk
            from subquestions
                inner join answer_choices
                    on answer_choices.subquestions_pk = subquestions.pk
                inner join question_responses
                    on question_responses.answer_choices_pk = answer_choices.pk
                inner join submissions
                    on question_responses.submission_pk = submission.pk
                where submissions.pk = 1
        ) subquery
            on subquery.questions_pk = questions.pk
order by    questions.order;
```

but depending on your dbms the former may perform better as it has no derived tables.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this, does it help?

```
SELECT  question_responses.answer_text
FROM    questions LEFT JOIN subquestions on (subquestions.questions_pk = questions.pk)
                  LEFT JOIN answer_choices on (answer_choices.subquestions_pk = subquestions.pk)
                  LEFT JOIN question_responses on (question_responses.answer_choices_pk = answer_choices.pk)
                  LEFT JOIN submissions on (question_responses.submission_pk = submission.pk)
WHERE submissions.pk = 1
ORDER BY  questions.order
```

Comment: That is what I attempted immediately after reading @Karl Kieninger 's comment.

No, the record is still missing.

Comment: oh all right. Is Submission.pk = 1 required? Were you able to work out something yet? Try joining two tables at a time. e.g. try joining questions, sub-questions and see the result and then try to add another table and see the result. You might be able to spot the issue.

Comment: Yes.  The criterion that I was using eliminated the record that I was interested in, so the left join doesn't amount to anything.  There is no way to accomplish what I wanted with a single query